# Saving data to mongodb database issues using nodejs and express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs, body-parser

I am having an issue with trying to save data parsed from the browser to my mongodb database it would be great if someone could explain to me why I am getting the error I am and how to fix it, thanks.

App.js:

```
var print = require('./print');
var port = 1338;
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:1337/testdb';
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    var collection = db.collection('users');
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connection established to', url);
    }
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.render("post");
        print("All is in order");
    })
    var collection = db.collection('users');
    var name = app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
        res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
        var name = req.body.name
        var user1 = { "username": name };
        collection.insert(user1, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Inserted %d documents into the "users" collection. The documents inserted with "_id" are:', result.length, result);
            }
        })
    });
    app.listen(port, function() {
        print(`listening on ${port}`);
    })
    db.close();
})
```

Post.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>CSS3 Contact Form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="contact">
        <h1>Send an email</h1>
        <form action="http://127.0.0.1:1338/post" method="post">
            <fieldset>
                <label for="name">Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" />
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" />
                <label for="message">Message:</label>
                <textarea id="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send message" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Error:

```
    { MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed
        at Function.MongoError.create (C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:29:11)
        at basicWriteValidations (C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:446:51)
        at Server.insert (C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\topologies\server.js:532:16)
        at Server.insert (C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server.js:383:17)
        at executeCommands (C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\ordered.js:455:23)
        at OrderedBulkOperation.execute (C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\ordered.js:508:10)
        at bulkWrite (C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:652:8)
        at Collection.insertMany (C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:522:44)
        at Collection.insert (C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:824:15)
        at C:\Users\Programming\Documents\Web_Repo\app.js:36:18
      name: 'MongoError',
      message: 'server instance pool was destroyed' }
```

Comment: It is because of `db.close()` . Since the code you wrote, runs asynchronously, it closes the connection even before fetching something.

Comment: Although it's not ideal how you wrote the code, but to quick fix the issue, you can put `db.close()` in the callback of `collection.insert`

Comment: Thanks it worked, but I must ask what is not ideal with the code structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Mukesh already told you the solution but like he mentioned your code structure can be improved.

So here's how I would do it,

**Config file ~config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    localUrl: 'mongodb://localhost/testDb',
    port: 1338
};
```

**main file**

```
var print = require('./print');
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
var config = require('./config.js');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("post");
    print("All is in order");
})

app.listen(config.port, function() {
   print(`listening on ${config.port}`);
})

MongoClient.connect(config.localUrl, function(err, db) {
    if(err) {
      console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err); 
      return; 
    }
    var collection = db.collection('users');
    app.post('/post', function(req, res) {
        res.send('You sent the name "' + req.body.name + '".');
        collection.insert({
         username : req.body.name
        }, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err); 
                db.close();
                return;
            } 
            db.close();
        })
    });

})
```

Comment: Np Kyle...I'm glad I helped...if my answer is what you were looking for you can upvote it

Comment: I am not able to upvote did you post it as a comment? if so you can repost it as an answer and  ill upvote it to give you the well deserved rep.

Comment: it is an answer, you can upvote it if you have at least 15 rep

Comment: Oh, bare with me then, ill up vote it eventually as I am a new user i only have 10 rep sadly.